# How do I separate multiple email addresses in cfmail

Tags: email, coldfusion, cfmail

Do I use a comma or semicolon? I can't seem to find it in the live docs. I also can't seem to find any consistency looking online as some examples use a comma while others use a semicolon. Are both acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmail.html

> Message recipient e-mail addresses:
>
> - Static address, for example, "support@.com".
> - Variable that contains an address, for example, "#Form.Email#".
> - Name of a query column that contains an address, for example,
>     "#EMail#". An e-mail message is sent
>     for each returned row.
>
> **To specify multiple addresses,
>   separate the addresses with commas.**

(emphasis mine)

I do believe semicolons will work as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either of them, and it should be fine. Although for consistency with existing email clients, I'd use a semicolon.

I'm not sure how commas would behave in other CF engines, such as Railo or OpenBD, whereas `;` would work on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Comma separate the email addresses is the answer i found in o'reilly's coldfusion book. its possible semi-colons will work, but commas for sure.

-Don

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on your mail server. If you're using Exchange, it expects semicolons. Most smtp servers prefer commas. Experiment and see what works for you.

Comment: CFMAIL uses SMTP, which uses commas.